# Laravel Homestead : How to fix 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem'

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, curl, homestead

I'm setting up a new Laravel 5.8 Homestead with VirtualBox, everything is ok except `curl` that gets me an

> 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem'

when using Guzzle client. (I do not want to ignore ssl)

Any idea ? Thanks a lot

I tried to replace :

```
curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

by

```
curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

in /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini (and also 7.1, 7.2)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, the problem seems solved. For those who have the same problem :

When you try to curl your own local websites over https, curl verifies that the certificate exists in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt, obviously it does not exist.

You have to open the certificate file generated by your Homestead.yaml with vim (or cat) located in :

```
/etc/nginx/ssl/ca.homestead.homestead.crt
```

and copy the contents at the end of the default ca-certificate.crt located in

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

It's quite normal that the default ca-certificates.crt does not contain your personal certificates.

That's all !

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure your `Homestead.yaml` contains `ssl: true` at root level
2. `vagrant ssh`
3. `cd /etc/nginx/ssl`
4. delete all cert files with `sudo rm ca.homestead.homestead.*` - or just move them to a temporary folder you can create on `/etc/nginx/ssl`
5. exit vagrant, and try `vagrant provision` - it will generate new cert files.
6. repeat steps 1 and 2
7. `cp ca.homestead.homestead.crt /home/vagrant/your-shared-directory` - For example, if in your Homestead configuration you have mapped `C:/username /home/vagrant/projects`, you should find the `ca.homestead.homestead.crt` into `C:/projects`.
8. Open your browser settings - `chrome://settings` for Chrome or `about:preferences#privacy` for Firefox
9. find *Manage / View Certificates*
10. Click Import and browse for the certificate you just copied from your virtual machine on to your local machine
11. Under the section labelled *Place all certificates in the following store*, find and select ***Trust Root Certification Authorities***.
12. Restart your web browser

If even after this procedure the error persists, but you can see a little padlock like [image] and your web application is constantly accessing some API, you may need to check if this API has a valid certification.

If this API cert is OK, you should check if your web application `.env` file for example is pointing the this API using `https://` or `http://` something like `API_URL=http://api.test`. Just edit it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if website is not using custom ssl certificate.

Try to open the certificates in chrome and exported all certificates and add them to a custom `custom.pem`

Then using it with Guzzle this way:

```
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('verify', '/path/to/custom.pem');
```

Now it might work!

You can also download a certificate with the [openssl command](https://superuser.com/a/641396/769336), but I my case it wasn't the right certificate. So I had to download them manually.

Hope this helps!

For more you can visit this [issue](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/394)

Comment: Receving this error: TypeError: Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp/Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, called in /vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 89

Comment: can you please elaborate your issue by showing what you have in your variable.